# How can I get the ordered elements of a JFace's TableViewer?

Tags: sorting, jface, tableviewer

I have implemented the JFace's TableViewer sorting according to [Vogella's instructions](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#sortcolumns) (reproduced below). It happens that the sorting is made in the graphical interface only (it is not reflected in the original data structure) and I need o get the elements in the order they are displayed in the GUI.

Alternatively, an implementation which reflects the sorting in the original data structure would fit too.

---

```java
package de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.sorter;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerComparator;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;

import de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.model.Person;

public class MyViewerComparator extends ViewerComparator {
  private int propertyIndex;
  private static final int DESCENDING = 1;
  private int direction = DESCENDING;

  public MyViewerComparator() {
    this.propertyIndex = 0;
    direction = DESCENDING;
  }

  public int getDirection() {
    return direction == 1 ? SWT.DOWN : SWT.UP;
  }

  public void setColumn(int column) {
    if (column == this.propertyIndex) {
      // Same column as last sort; toggle the direction
      direction = 1 - direction;
    } else {
      // New column; do an ascending sort
      this.propertyIndex = column;
      direction = DESCENDING;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(Viewer viewer, Object e1, Object e2) {
    Person p1 = (Person) e1;
    Person p2 = (Person) e2;
    int rc = 0;
    switch (propertyIndex) {
    case 0:
      rc = p1.getFirstName().compareTo(p2.getFirstName());
      break;
    case 1:
      rc = p1.getLastName().compareTo(p2.getLastName());
      break;
    case 2:
      rc = p1.getGender().compareTo(p2.getGender());
      break;
    case 3:
      if (p1.isMarried() == p2.isMarried()) {
        rc = 0;
      } else
        rc = (p1.isMarried() ? 1 : -1);
      break;
    default:
      rc = 0;
    }
    // If descending order, flip the direction
    if (direction == DESCENDING) {
      rc = -rc;
    }
    return rc;
  }

}
```

---

```java
package de.vogella.jface.tableviewer;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

import de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.model.ModelProvider;
import de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.model.Person;
import de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.sorter.MyViewerComparator;

public class View extends ViewPart {
  public static final String ID = "de.vogella.jface.tableviewer.view";
  private MyViewerComparator comparator;

  private TableViewer viewer;
  // We use icons
  private static final Image CHECKED = Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/checked.gif").createImage();
  private static final Image UNCHECKED = Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/unchecked.gif").createImage();

  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
    parent.setLayout(layout);
    Label searchLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
    searchLabel.setText("Search: ");
    final Text searchText = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER | SWT.SEARCH);
    searchText.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL
        | GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_FILL));
    createViewer(parent);
    // Set the sorter for the table
    comparator = new MyViewerComparator();
    viewer.setComparator(comparator);

  }

  private void createViewer(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
        | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
    createColumns(parent, viewer);
    final Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
    // Get the content for the viewer, setInput will call getElements in the
    // contentProvider
    viewer.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getPersons());
    // Make the selection available to other views
    getSite().setSelectionProvider(viewer);

    // Layout the viewer
    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
    gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);
  }

  public TableViewer getViewer() {
    return viewer;
  }

  // This will create the columns for the table
  private void createColumns(final Composite parent, final TableViewer viewer) {
    String[] titles = { "First name", "Last name", "Gender", "Married" };
    int[] bounds = { 100, 100, 100, 100 };

    // First column is for the first name
    TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
      @Override
      public String getText(Object element) {
        Person p = (Person) element;
        return p.getFirstName();
      }
    });

    // Second column is for the last name
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], bounds[1], 1);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
      @Override
      public String getText(Object element) {
        Person p = (Person) element;
        return p.getLastName();
      }
    });

    // Now the gender
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[2], bounds[2], 2);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
      @Override
      public String getText(Object element) {
        Person p = (Person) element;
        return p.getGender();
      }
    });

    // // Now the status married
    col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[3], bounds[3], 3);
    col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
      @Override
      public String getText(Object element) {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Image getImage(Object element) {
        if (((Person) element).isMarried()) {
          return CHECKED;
        } else {
          return UNCHECKED;
        }
      }
    });

  }

  private TableViewerColumn createTableViewerColumn(String title, int bound,
      final int colNumber) {
    final TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer,
        SWT.NONE);
    final TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
    column.setText(title);
    column.setWidth(bound);
    column.setResizable(true);
    column.setMoveable(true);
    column.addSelectionListener(getSelectionAdapter(column, colNumber));
    return viewerColumn;
  }

  private SelectionAdapter getSelectionAdapter(final TableColumn column,
      final int index) {
    SelectionAdapter selectionAdapter = new SelectionAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        comparator.setColumn(index);
        int dir = comparator.getDirection();
        viewer.getTable().setSortDirection(dir);
        viewer.getTable().setSortColumn(column);
        viewer.refresh();
      }
    };
    return selectionAdapter;
  }


/** * Passing the focus request to the viewer's control. */

  public void setFocus() {
    viewer.getControl().setFocus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDITED:

```java
TableItem[] items = viewer.getTable().getItems();

MyObject[] objectsInGui = new MyObject[items.length];
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    objectsInGui[i] = (MyObject) items[i].getData();
}
```

The second approach (which wasn't required):

```java
Method getRoot = StructuredViewer.getMethod("getRoot");
getRoot.setAccessible(true);
Method getSortedChildren = StructuredViewer.getMethod("getSortedChildren", Object.class);
getSortedChildren.setAccessible(true);
Object root = getRoot.invoke(viewer);
Object[] objectsInGui = getSortedChildren.invoke(viewer, root);
```

or use `getFilters()` and `getComparator()` and filter and sort using them.

Comment: `Table.getItems()` returns the already sorted items indeed. Unfortunately, I'll have to copy the entire array (which may grow quite big sometimes) two times -- one of them is in your solution and the other is for casting `Object[]` into one of `MyObject[]` using `Arrays.copyOf(Object[] orig, int length, Class<MyObject[]> type)`.

Comment: Ah.. Ok. I think I had in mind the decoupling between Model and View (avoiding references of Model objects in the View and, primarily, the other way around). But given the potential inefficiency the architecture will have to be a little more flexible. Thank you very much!

Comment: You could try to make it generic then. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation for some help.