# TableViewer.getElementAt() returning a filtered element

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm trying to automatically select the first item in a filtered table.

I'm essentially doing the following:

```
table = new TableViewer(...);
table.addFilter(filter);
table.setContentProvider(contentProvider);
table.setInput(input);
first = table.getElementAt(0);
table.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(first));
```

The surprising thing is that (depending on the filter) I can get an element that is filtered out from `getElementAt(0)`. The result is that ultimately, no item will be selected.

I have tried calling `table.refresh()` before getting the element with the same results.

If I call `getElementAt(0)` at a later point, I do indeed get the correct first element (that is not filtered out).

How can I make `getElementAt` respect the filtering immediately?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_filter) under heading "Filtering data 2.2"

Comment: @Joel Doesn't really help. As I said, I tried calling refresh() but still got the filtered item.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464059/how-can-i-get-the-ordered-elements-of-a-jfaces-tableviewer check. apply the same logic.

Comment: try using table.getInput().get(0)

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found what was wrong and it was my own fault. The filter I set is mutable so it can filter more or less strictly. The problem was that I activated the more strict filtering *after* I set the selection.

Thanks everyone for the help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most reliable way to select the first (visible) element is - for once only - to bypass JFace, rely on its internal data model, and use SWT API to select the first `TableItem` like this:

```
static Object selectFirstElement(TableViewer tableViewer) {
  Object firstElement = null;
  Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
  if (table.getItemCount() > 0) {
    firstElement = table.getItem(0).getData();
    tableViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(firstElement), true); // true == reveal
  }
  return firstElement;
}
```

I've been using this code successfully for several years with sorted, filtered, and virtual tables.